# How to properly marshal unmanaged arrays in c# without unsafe

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have unmanaged structure:

```
typedef struct 
 {
    char  a[48];
    BYTE  b;
    BYTE  c;
    BYTE  d;            
    BYTE  e;            
    BYTE  f;
    BYTE  x;
    char  y[32];
    char  z[128][32];
  }SOMELIKE_STRUCT
```

I tried to marshal it as it was written in another threads in StackOverflow:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
    public struct SOMELIKE_STRUCT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 48)]
        public byte[] a;
        [FieldOffset(48)]
        public byte b;
        [FieldOffset(49)]
        public byte c;
        [FieldOffset(50)]
        public byte d;
        [FieldOffset(51)]
        public byte e;
        [FieldOffset(52)]
        public byte f;
        [FieldOffset(53)]
        public byte x;
        [FieldOffset(54)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 32)]
        public byte[] y;
        [FieldOffset(86)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 128)]
        public STRUCT[] z;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
    public struct STRUCT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 32)]
        public byte[] name;
    }
```

I have exception:

System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
  Additional information: Could not load type 'SOMELIKE_STRUCT' from assembly
     'ConsoleApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because
     it contains an object field at offset '54' that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped
     by a non-object field.

1. Exception shows when I create this struct with new:

   SOMELIKE_STRUCT l = new SOMELIKE_STRUCT();
2. Exception shows when I will create class (when step into constructor) using that structure (before create instance of that structure)

Comment: Managed array object references must be aligned to provide the memory model guarantee that updating such a reference is always atomic.  If the [FieldOffset] values are correct then you must declare the arrays with the `fixed` keyword to avoid this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures and tables contained in **struct** have to be placed at address being multiple of word (4/8 bytes for x86/x64).

Answer (score 3):

Can't quite figure out what's going on here as your definitions seems correct.

Changing the layout to sequential and removing the manual field offsets seems to work:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct SOMELIKE_STRUCT
{
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 48 )]
    public byte[] a;
    public byte b;
    public byte c;
    public byte d;
    public byte e;
    public byte f;
    public byte x;
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 32 )]
    public byte[] y;
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 128 )]
    public STRUCT[] z;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct STRUCT
{
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 32 )]
    public byte[] name;
}
```

Checking the size with `Marshal.SizeOf` gives 4182 bytes, and checking the resulting layout with `Marshal.OffsetOf` gives the same offsets as in your original code. I'm sure someone else here can elaborate on why this is happening.